# how do I get a variable in scoop in swift so I can pass it data?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

how do I get my serialnumberLabel in scoop of the itemsviewController when its in a different file and where would I put it because I'm new to swift I know very little please help

[image: this is my viewcontroller]

[image: THIS is my tableCell TableViewCell]

Comment: To understand how this works you really just need to, in the simplest way, think this through. You have a view controller and a cell and in that cell you have a label. I see you have a method that handles a user's tap action. So tell us, in the big picture of things, what you're trying to accomplish. What is the user tapping and what is the tap supposed to do?

Comment: And it's in scope, not scoop.

Answer (score 0):

You should reload current tableView in `completionHandle` closure and store `text` in `ItemsViewController`, then update `serialNumberLabel.text` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change logic by steps:

Step1: Make a list common model for table view

Step2: when you modify item you set for model common in table view.

Step3: when you callback item you can only call reload table view.

All done.